# Can you move and tilt to aim using a DualShock 4?

Tags: ps4

On the PlayStation Vita I can aim by moving & tilting the console in these games: Killzone and Gravity Rush.

Does the DualShock 4 on the PS 4 allow this feature?

Comment: I disagree. Its asking whether a console feature is supported for a certain type of input device.

Comment: @FooBarrigno Before it was edited, it was also asking "how many games utilize this feature." But I agree that since that part's been edited out, there's now no problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the DualShock 4 does allow the feature.

> The controller supports motion detection via a three-axis gyroscope
>   and three-axis accelerometer and vibration.

It's the same technology as in the old DualShock 3 controllers (Six-axis motion sensing system (three-axis gyroscope, three-axis accelerometer)) - [See here.](http://www.scei.co.jp/corporate/release/130221b_e.html)  You'll have to scroll down a bit to where it gives the technical specifications for the DualShock 4 controller.

As far as I'm aware, no games currently support this functionality though.  The new Killzone definitely does not.

Comment: Battlefield 4 does, you can use it to lean around corners, not many people seem to know or use this though.